# Rails seed not creating instances in databases while db:seed

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a small e-commerce like API. I'm trying to create mock users with Faker and creating an instance of a Shopping cart attahced with it as a foreign key during the seed (Each user should have a shopping cart). I tried two different methods

These fils are in the seed.rb file in the db folder
Try 1:
    5.times do
      Product.create({
                         title: Faker::Commerce.product_name,
                         price: Faker::Commerce.price,
                         inventory_count: Faker::Number.number(2)
                     })

```
end

3.times do
  ShoppingCart.create({
                                 total_price: 0
                             }) do |t|


  User.create({
                  name: Faker::Name.name,
                  shopping_carts_id: t.id
              })
    end
end
```

try 2: (Identical creation of products)

3.times do
      cart = ShoppingCart.create({
                                     total_price: 0
                                 })

```
  User.create({
                  name: Faker::Name.name,
                  shopping_carts_id: cart.id
              })
    end
end
```

Here is the model

```
class ShoppingCart < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :users
  has_many :products
end
```

When I run the seed, the users are created fine but no Shopping carts are there. There should be a foreign key from user to it's shopping cart. I'm very new to rails and am having a hard time understanding the db relationships.

Comment: Remember that with Ruby the `{ ... }` braces are optional for hash-only argument lists. Like instead of `User.create({ name: '...' })` you can do `User.create(name: '...')` which is a lot more concise. That might also address some of the really wonky indentation here.

Comment: Try calling create! On both and see if an error is raised

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a foreign key via migrations and seeing what the result is?

`rails g migration AddForeignKeyToShoppingCart`

Then in the new migration file, add this:

```
def change
  add_foreign_key :shopping_carts, :users
end
```